# Web Deploy resets IIS settings for Handler Mappings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, publishing, webdeploy

I'm using web deploy to publish a MVC4 project, and every time I publish it my Handler Mappings get reset and I have to add a new one.

Is there a way I can include this setting in the publish, or set it not to refresh the handler mappings?

I have my publish settings at default, where "Include IIS Settings as configured in IIS Express" is NOT checked.

Answer (score 2):

Web Deploy simply deploys your Web.config, potentially with transforms applied. It will always replace the web.config on the server though so you might want to check if the web.config in your project is correct.